# Running methods Aysnchronously in Rest API in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, concurrency

How should I decide which REST methods to be annotated with @Async and why we require some methods to be annotated @Async ?

For example

```
@RestController
public class controller {

    
    private  employeeservice eserv;

    @GetMapping(value = "/emp")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees()
    {
        return this.eserv.getEmployees();
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/emp")
    public Employee addemployee(@RequestBody Employee emp)
    {
        return this.eserv.addemployee(emp);
    }
}
```

This is service class example

```
@Service
public class employeeserviceimpl implements employeeservice {

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee addemployee(Employee emp) {
        list.add(emp);
        return emp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using MVC and RestController your requests will be synchronous.

If you want to call multiple methods in parallel from the controller method or you don't want to wait for the result you can annotated the service methods `@Async`.